# Convex risk measure and a coherent risk measure?

Tags: risk, coherent-risk-measure, convexity

A coherent risk measure is:

$\rho(\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda X_2))$

How can it be shown that everey convex risk measure is indeed a coherent risk measure?

I assume that it is enough to show that a convex risk measure is coherent by using, subadditivity, positive homogeniety. So we get: $\rho(\lambda X_1+(1-\lambda X_2))=\rho(\lambda X_1)+\rho((1-\lambda)X_2)=\lambda \rho(X_1)+(1-\lambda)\rho(X_2))$ right?

Comment: What does your first formula say? This is $\rho$ of something .. this is no property not theorem .. just nothing.

Comment: $\rho$ is a risk measure

Comment: the first formula is still not a statement ...

Answer (score 2):

We define a convex risk measure as 
$$
\rho( \lambda X_1 + (1-\lambda) X_2) \le \lambda \rho(  X_1 ) + (1-\lambda) \rho(X_2),
$$
for $\lambda  \in(0,1) $.

A coherent risk measure is subadditive and homogeneous thus for coherent $\rho$ we get:
$$
\rho( \lambda X_1 + (1-\lambda) X_2) \le \rho( \lambda X_1) + \rho( (1-\lambda) X_2) 
$$
by subadditivity and
$$
\rho( \lambda X_1) + \rho( (1-\lambda) = \lambda \rho(X_1) + (1-\lambda)\rho(X_2)
$$
by homogeneity. Thus a coherent risk measure is convex. The reverse is not true in general.

Comment: So a convex risk measure satisfies 3 axioms: convexity, subadditivity and homogeniety?

Comment: no, but if you have subadditivity and homogeneity then you automatically have a convex risk measure. This is what "implied" means. Coherent implies convex. Thus convex is more general.

Comment: Every coherent measure is convex. The reverse is not true (but maybe in a lot of cases ... still not in general).

Comment: The entropic risk measure (not to be confused with entropic value-at-risk) is an example of a risk measure that is convex but not coherent.